# JSON library version mismatch

Tags: .net, json.net, app-config, .net-4.6.1, assembly-binding-redirect

Every Newtonsoft.Json.dll reference in projects, has maximum version of 12.0.3. In builded bin folder, in app.exe.config there is

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

There is not even single line in project which could refer to the v 13.0.0 of Json library. In bin folder, Newtonsoft.Json.dll is in 12.0.3 version. how app.exe.config knows, that there is v13 available?

My App.config part about Newtonsoft.Json library looks like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: What does your app.config file look like?  What external assemblies are you referencing?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.1 has reached End Of Life. All supported Windows versions come with a newer version

Comment: Is Json.NET your only dependent assembly?  Or are there others that might be bringing in newer Json.NET versions?